# How to write prewritten HTML codes on WordPress post

Tags: html, wordpress

Currently, I'm manually adding the  tag below on each of my post.

```
<div class="js-video [vimeo, widescreen]" style="text-align: center;">
</div>
```

So, i wish to prewrite the tags above right after the  and right before the  on WordPress post, so that these tags will be automatically written on each post.

So, each time I create a new post (not page), I get the div tags already encapsulating the post body. I'm actually trying to add a single video with a vimeo iframe in the post encapsulated with the div tags.

Which PHP file should I change on WordPress and roughly which line?

Comment: It depends on how you design your theme. But basically you need to understand the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) first.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, i need to change one of these files. Yes?

single-{post-type}-{slug}.php – (Since 4.4) First, WordPress looks for a template for the specific post. For example, if post type is product and the post slug is dmc-12, WordPress would look for single-product-dmc-12.php.
single-{post-type}.php – If the post type is product, WordPress would look for single-product.php.
single.php – WordPress then falls back to single.php.

Comment: Yes, the most basic files would be single.php and index.php, the rest depend on your theme or your design.

Comment: It may involved other pages as well, such as header.php and footer.php, etc., but you provide no information on which part of the page you want to add the html tag, so this is the basic answer i could provided.

Comment: I'm looking at changing only the post, meaning not page. So, each time I create a new post, i get the div tags already encapsulating the post body. I'm actually trying to add a single video with a vimeo iframe in the post encapsulated with the div tag.

Comment: then it should be in single.php. both page and post could use the single.php, what you need is to check if the $post_type=="post" then add the html tag. See details at [Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types).

Comment: Your question is kind of *too broad* as more than one way exists to do this (modifying the theme would be one of them). I think the most effective is using the filter shown in the duplicates, and use a [conditional tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) as one of the answers shows.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you create your theme. If you understand WordPress theme hierarchy, then you have to look at the most specific file for single post, and then add your code into it.

Comment: Nvm, I found the answer here, http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-default-content-in-your-wordpress-post-editor/